# What does "index to list" mean?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm super new to python, in a class, and the current assignment is:

"Write a function that takes a list, index to list, and another index to list and swaps the data in the list at the two indexes of the single list."

I have no idea what my teacher is trying to get me to do. 
Can anyone explain this in layman's terms?

Comment: If you are new to Python, you should know thar there is a lot of [on-line documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/). (The same documentation should be part of a local Python install, btw.)  In this case the [documentation about sequence types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) would be a useful read.

Comment: @RolandSmith - it sounds as if the OP is also new to programming in general, so concepts like an "index" into a "list" would still be foreign. The Python documentation is well written, but doesn't explain, for example, what an index *is*.

Comment: @iAdjunct One would expect the teacher to have covered the concept of lists before handing out an assignment like this! But if not it is well covered in the tutorial, specifically "[An Informal Introduction to Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html)".

Comment: @RolandSmith - that is true: one would hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is an ordered collection of objects. For example, you may have a list of students in a class *(who are engaged in a brutal fight club, but for obvious reasons never discuss it)*:

```
list = [
    "Christopher" , # Christopher is the best fighter, so he's first in the list
    "John" ,
    "Alex" ,
    "Sarah" ,
    "Elizabeth"
]
```

Let's say you want to give the list to somebody, but also want to tell them that you care about `"Alex"` in that list. How do you do that?

You could also give them the string `"Alex"`, but then the other person has to figure out where in the list `"Alex"` is.

Instead, you give them an *index* into the list - which is a number that describes which item in the list you're thinking about. For example, the index for `"Alex"` in the aforementioned list is `2`...

...which leads me to an important note: lists are "0-indexed" [in most languages], which means that you start counting at 0 (so Christopher is 0, John is 1, Alex is 2, Sarah is 3, and Elizabeth is 4). Therefore:

```
print list[1]
```

Prints this:

```
John
```

So what your professor is saying is that you should write a function where somebody gives you a list, and two indexes into that list, and you're supposed to **swap them** *(bold because you can search Stack Overflow for how to **swap items in a list** and get good answers to show you your path).*

So, let's say I give you the above list, and the indexes `1` and `4`. I am basically telling you to swap John and Elizabeth in the list (perhaps John and Elizabeth got in a fight to determine who should be the #2 person in their class and Elizabeth won, for example.....)

The result from your function should then look like:

```
list = [
    "Christopher" , # item 0
    "Elizabeth" , # item 1
    "Alex" , # item 2
    "Sarah" , # item 3
    "John" # item 4
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This made perfect sense and I was able to find more articles that helped me complete my assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your list is [A, B, C, D, E] and you are given 3, 1 as your indices.

You should swap the item at index 3 (D) and index 1 (B), such that the list now:

[A, D, C, B, E]

I am assuming that he wants you to do this swap 'in place'. By that, he does not want you to create a new list. You should modify the original list.

I would confirm with your professor to make sure you do not lose points.